# Crontab, scheduled jobs, on holidays

Tags: shell, ubuntu, cron

I wrote  a shell script for monitoring a Rest API, when it is down the shell script send two mails one for the developer and the other for the manager. The problem is that I need to this with this frequency:

- Runs every 15 min during office hours (9-18 hours) during working days and send mail to manager and developer
- Every hour 6-9 pm and from 18 to 24h on working days runs and sends mail to manager.
- Runs every 3 hours from 00:00 to 6:00 every night and the holidays and send mail to manager

¿How can I discard between holidays and work days?

Comment: Run your cronjob every 15 minutes. The script should be responsible for checking the date/time and exiting early if it should not run at *this* time.

Comment: What is your definition of 'holidays'?

Comment: days that the office is closed, for example christmas day, os 1st january

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need several entries:

1. Every 15 min during office hours

   */15 09-18 * * * yourscript.sh
2. Send email only to manager, add an if inside the script that will check for the hour and send only to the manager

   00 06-09,18-23 * * * yourscript.sh
3. Send every three hours

   00 00,03,06 * * * yourscript.sh

For not running on holidays, cron will not be able to help, you will need to get from a different source a file which lists all the holidays and then add an if inside your script.

```
#!/bin/sh 
if [ grep -q `date +%F` /random_location/holidays.txt]; then    
   exit 0   
fi

# Continue your script from here
```

Comment: What do you actually put in the holidays.txt? Cron expressions equal to the dates of certain holidays?

Comment: As `date +%F` outputs something like 2017-06-23 no, you have to add valid date strings like this

Answer (score 2):

For not running on a holiday, put that date in the holidays.txt. In the crontab have an entry like

```
* * * * * grep -q `date -I` holidays.txt || yourscript.sh
```

Preferably use full path for both holidays.txt and yourscript.sh

Comment: Can you explain for other readers a bit more about how this works?  Should the line you showed be added to your existing crontab lines; what do the 5 stars do, etc.

Comment: @John - It's a line in the crontab. It looks pretty simple and genius to me... the 5 stars are the normal stuff you see in any cron file, and instead of just giving it a script like most people, he's instead having it check the holidays.txt file, and then only running the script if today isn't in that file.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - that's clever.